# Xarray distance based sliding window in lat and lon system?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I need to select all pixels within 50km of a central pixel in a lat and long coordinate system. I could do the loop but that is not ideal. Currently the `rolling` function in `xarray` is based on fixed window size. This doesn't work for me since the number of cells within 50 km depends on the latitude (more pixels in higher latitudes).  Is there any efficient way to construct windows based on variable window size? Here is an example of fixed window:

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("ersstv5")
ds_roll = ds.rolling({"lat": 5, "lon": 5}, center=True).construct(
    {"lat": "lat_dim", "lon": "lon_dim"}
)
```

I am looking for a way to make the window size dynamic based on certain distance from a central window.
Thanks